# Max Number of Columns in Bar Chart- Oracle ADF

Tags: bar-chart, oracle-adf

I use  JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0

I want  control Bar Chart columns Number not Want it Display  all values at

selected column just want  display first 10 columns .. without change any thing in viewobject Query
Can I do From bar chart properties ?? and if yes  .. from where ??